# VB.NET how to handle a json oddly formatted

Tags: json, vb.net, json-deserialization

I have this json:

```
POST /API/AlarmEvent/EventPush HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.2.103:123
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 112652

{"result":"success","data":{"EventType":"LPD","EventTime":"2015-1-19 4:33:4","EventAction":"start","ChannelName":"PERGENOVA","DeviceName":"BS-IPT4704G3MZ+","IPAddress":"192.168.2.168","MacAddress":"00-23-63-92-25-47","PicData":{"PlateInfo":[{"Id":"","GrpId":3,"SnapId":"AH234MG","Type":10,"StrChn":"CH1","StartTime":1421641983,"EndTime":1421641987,"Chn":0,"Sex":0,"PlateColor":0,"CarBrand":"","CarType":"","Owner":"","IdCode":"","Job":"","Phone":"","Domicile":"","Remark":"","PlateImg":"/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQIAdgB2AAD/7wAPAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAP/bAEMAAwICAwICAwMDAwQDAwQFCAUFBAQFCgcHBggMCgwMC...=="}]}}}
```

nb for the sake of readability I truncated PlateImg data because it is a string of > 100k byte.

What is the best practice to deserialize just the json data leaving out the first part?

```
POST /API/AlarmEvent/EventPush HTTP/1.1
Host: 192.168.2.103:123
Accept: */*
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 112652
```

I did this, it's working, but I find it ugly:

```
text = text.Split(vbLf)(6).ToString
```

EDIT:
Here's the code of the tcp listener

```
Dim _server As TcpListener

Sub tcpListenerINIT()
        Try
            Dim ip As String = My.Settings.tcpListenerIP
            Dim port As Integer = My.Settings.tcpListenerPort

            _server = New TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(ip), port)
            _server.Start()

            Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf NewClient)

        Catch ex As Exception
            Console.WriteLine(ex)
        End Try
End Sub

Private Sub NewClient(state As Object)
        Try

            Using client As TcpClient = _server.AcceptTcpClient()
                Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(AddressOf NewClient)

                Using ns As NetworkStream = client.GetStream()
                    Dim buffer As New MemoryStream() ' Use MemoryStream as a dynamic buffer

                    Dim bytesRead As Integer
                    Dim receiveBuffer(4096) As Byte ' Buffer to read incoming data in chunks

                    Do
                        bytesRead = ns.Read(receiveBuffer, 0, receiveBuffer.Length)
                        If bytesRead > 0 Then
                            buffer.Write(receiveBuffer, 0, bytesRead)
                        End If
                    Loop While bytesRead > 0

                    buffer.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin) ' Reset the position of the MemoryStream

                    Dim receivedData(buffer.Length) As Byte
                    buffer.Read(receivedData, 0, receivedData.Length)

                    ' Now you have the complete message in the receivedData array as bytes.

                    If receivedData.Length > My.Settings.minLenghtForSuccess Then
                        Dim text As String = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(receivedData)
                        [CODE]
                    End If
                End Using
            End Using

        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
End sub
```

Comment: That looks like you've taken the whole HTTP response: headers and body. Your HTTP client will be able to separate these.

Comment: What's the code you're using to get that 'json',  it's not normal to get the header info so might be a case of fixing that and then you don't have a problem

Comment: Please remove all the `Catch ex As Exception`. It's such a bad coding practice.

Comment: @Enigmativity why's that?

Comment: @GabrieleCozzolino - When you swallow errors (or do something trivial like logging) then you are hiding issues with your code. You should only ever catch ***specific*** exceptions that you can ***meaningfully*** handle. You should learn to code defensively and understand what exceptions can occur and ***prevent*** them in the first place (where possible). Please read https://ericlippert.com/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/

Comment: @Enigmativity I understand that, sometimes I use it just to display a meaningful error while in development

Comment: @GabrieleCozzolino - That's worse. The dev environment should show you far more information on what is going on.

Comment: @Enigmativity noted. Can you also share something more related to my question? Thanks

Comment: @GabrieleCozzolino - `text.Split(vbLf)(6).ToString()` is the way to go.